# JasperReports, export to PDF, blank new lines

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

JasperReports library seems to be miscalculating how many new lines the text field need to fit all its contents. In JasperReports Studio (in preview) everything looks fine, but not when exporting to PDF from my application.

I've read PDF FAQ from JasperReports and I tried setting `PROPERTY_FORCE_LINEBREAK_POLICY` in the report to `true`, but this didn't make any difference. I also experimented with various fonts, but then in runtime Java complained about missing font in AWT, so I guess my default font (`SansSerif`) is just fine.

When I print "english only" version of the report, then everything looks okay, because all texts are about a half in length, but when using longer texts (like in example below) then this line miscalculation happens.

Here is how it looks right now and I marked unwanted extra lines with red:
[image]

Since I've tried with both hints from JasperReport's PDF FAQ, what else can I do?

Comment: Note, that each pair of "label - value" (like for Buyer name) is put into a separate frame, where both name and value can stretch with overflow (option enabled) and they both have "stretch to tallest object", but as I understand this stretches to tallest object in this frame, so for example "buyer name" should not be stratched - both label and value fit in single line, right?

Comment: The blank line below top title is really weird. It's just single text field - no streching to tallest objects or anything like that. Only stretching with overflow is enabled. The smaller subtitle should be right below the top title, but instead it's after another blank line.

Comment: You should use font extension for your report and then check that you don't have difference from style (If defined) and font definition and textField, I have seen this when example style is defined not bold, font-extension without bold .ttf but font in textField is bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Switch all fonts to Dejavu (I used to use default fonts)
2. Have a `jasperreports-fonts` extension included in the project.

The new font is a tiny bit wider, but that's okay. Other than that it looks very alike.